# Regex pattern to avoid match certain words like customize negation

Tags: python, regex

I am having a regular expression to match a particular pattern. Say, a pattern that will match all three letter words. But i want it to not match words like 'and','got' etc... What would be the best way to do it ,in Python.

My pattern is

```
r'\b\w{3}\b'
```

I tried

```
r'(\b\w{3}\b)(?!and)'
```

but fails.

Comment: @nu11p01n73R - The problem was to add some exceptional word that this pattern should skip. You solved a lot of previous issues of mine. Thanks man.

Comment: I miss read the question. Totally missed the point that you need to match all three letter words other than `and got etc` :(

Comment: @nu11p01n73R - its okay man. You guys are really helpful to us solving problems and learning new tips.

Comment: Its a great learning experience for me also. Glad to help always :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regexes match left to right, and lookaheads are no exception. Your expression will match three letters  *that are not followed by `and`* (which is impossible because of the `\b`, by the way).

Move the lookahead before the `\w` to make it work:

```
r'(\b(?!and)\w{3}\b)'
```

You can add more words there --

```
r'(\b(?!and|got|may)\w{3}\b)'
```

but for more non-matches it may be more effective to match *all* three letter words and use code to strip the result of them.

Comment: Thanks man. So it seems like it will skip all the words like and,got etc while moving from left to right ??? Is that correct .

Comment: Yes. See http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html for a longer description.